# How to change the tab close mark "X" color when mouse cursor touches on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one TabControl with multiple pages. Each page has a close mark "X" on tab. I want to the "X" color changed to white when mouse cursor touches (within an area) the "X", so that reminding us that cursor within that area. The codes are as following:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //This code will render a "x" mark at the end of the Tab caption. 
        e.Graphics.DrawString("X", e.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds.Right - 20, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 24, e.Bounds.Top + 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Div1, new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + 2));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
        //Getting the position of the "x" mark.
        Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 20, r.Top + 4, 20, 10);
        if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            //how to write here to change tab caption color or close mark "X" color
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to force a repaint so your DrawItem event handler runs gain.  Call tabControl1.Invalidate().  Also when it needs to have its original color again of course, use a *bool* variable.

Comment: Dont test it in the mousemove but in the drawitem event! thn draw either one or another image. to test either use the last e.location you can store in th mousemove or simply get a current one from from the  tabControl1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

Comment: TaW, thanks for your message. How to fire the event when cursor touches the mark "X" within tabControl1_DrawItem?